# UK visa refusal for self-employed individual

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, international-travel, indonesian-citizens

I want to visit my boyfriend in the UK for 8 days.

My visa was refused because I'm unemployed and I forgot to explain that my family supported me financially on a day-to-day basis in my country. I said that I will go back to my country to find a job.

I'm planning to reapply. Actually I have a online shop (selling makeup) on Instagram. I said I was unemployed because I don't know what documents are needed for entrepreneurs. My annual income isn’t really big but it's enough to support me  financially for my day-to-day needs, cause I live with my parents.

What should I do next? Do I need to say that I'm self-employed instead of unemployed, and tell about my online shop?

I read that if we own a business, we need to submit business registration. Based on the rules and regulations of the government in my country, a business with a profit of under Rp 200,000,000 (£100,000) does not require a Business registration. I don't have any assets either. I'm from Indonesia.

I'm so confused right now. Please help me.

[image: picture of the UK visa refusal document]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) @Hana This is not what you want to hear but with your profile (unemployed, supported by family, undocumented earnings from an online shop) and with one refusal already, it’s highly unlikely you’ll be getting a UK visa any time soon. You can’t credibly address the refusal reasons quickly and IMHO you’ll just be wasting your money if you reapply

Comment: No  but i can show them the transactions between my customers with me. Im selling in instagram and a platform like amazon. Is it ok if I change that im self employed? And if i can show them the business registration, u think will i get a visa?

Comment: How will you explain why you said you were unemployed in your previous application, whilst presenting evidence of earnings pre-dating the application?

Comment: Because i think if saying my boyfriend pay all my expenses it will be ok, and i dont know any information what documents needed for entrepreneurs.  Do u have any suggestions  what’s the best reasons to come back to my country. I attached a letter from my mum and her doctor saying that my mum is sick and need my help.

Comment: No, this won't work. The visa officer already believes that your boyfriend will pay your expenses, so explaining that more won't help. You visa was refused because they don't believe that you'll return to Indonesia after your visit -- you have no job to go back to and you'd be leaving your boyfriend behind. If you change your story, you're just admitting that you lied on your first application, which makes your situation worse, not better. An online business is unlikely to help because it being online means you could do the work illegally in the UK instead of returning.

Comment: So no chance for me?